# Using jQuery Hotkeys to Select Text Area without writing text

Tags: jquery, textarea, hotkeys, jquery-hotkeys

I am using [jeresig's jQuery Hotkeys library](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) to enable hotkeys that can select a text area on a webpage. However, when I use the hotkey, it inserts text into the text area instead of only selecting it, overwriting the previous content, which is not what I want. Is there a solution to this?

HTML:

```
<input id='test' type='text' value='content'> <span class='button'>Button</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Clicking button selects associated text area
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('input:text').focus();
    });

    // Hotkeys for text area
    $(document).bind('keypress', 'a', function () {
        $('#test').focus()
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7M6m/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `keypress` event, it can be executed many times. Use `keyup` instead.